# Should I accept an answer to a question that I haven't tried out (because my use case is no longer valid)?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Here is my situation:

My question: [mongoengine - Ignore extra fields for schema validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495037/mongoengine-ignore-extra-fields-for-schema-validation)

I asked a question in April 2015 and I did not receive an acceptable answer within the timeframe that my question was valid. I resolved the problem with a redesign within the month.

About 8 months later a user answered my original question and got quite a few upvotes for it. Now I'm asking myself: should I accept this answer even though it is no longer valid for my use case and I haven't tried it out? Should I trust the community of upvoters that the answer is valid?

Comment: The accepted answer should be the most helpful answer to you or the one that solved your problem.  If that does not apply then I would suggest you not accept it.  Answers do not need to be accepted by the OP.

Comment: If you'd received the answer within a few days or so but your use case had changed, then it'd be good manners (IMHO) to test it anyway, and accept it if it's good or perhaps give the author some feedback if you felt that the answer was unacceptable. But you're certainly under no obligation to do that, and when an answer is months late the author should know that their answer may no longer be of any use to the OP, although it may be of interest to future readers.

Comment: IMHO it is also good manners to explain, in a comment, in this scenario when the solution invalidates the question for you, or in an answer you accept, your solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Should I trust the community of upvoters that the answer is valid?

No.  The community is already using votes to reflect what it feels the value of that answer is.  The accept mark is for you to indicate that you feel it is the correct answer.  If you don't *know* if it's the correct answer, then you shouldn't indicate otherwise.  Any future readers already have the votes of the community to know what the community feels of the answer.

Now, that doesn't necessarily mean you need to still have the problem you once did in order to accept an answer, it just means that you should feel confident in saying that you know the answer is correct, and that you're willing to put your name on that, before you accept it as the answer.